# Can't load Jquery and dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to use Data Tables, but it's not loading JQuery and DataTables. I'm trying to use this example: 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html
but Data Tables don't load at all, only my table.
My code is:

```html
    <html>
<head>
 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css"  />

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<?php
$survey_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

 echo "<div class='col-md-9'>";

echo '<table border="0" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
 
echo validation_errors();

foreach ($survey as $row)
{ 
 
 echo "<tr>";
 echo form_open('index/survey_fill/' .$survey_id );
    echo "<td class='col-md-9'>"; 
 echo "$row->question";
 
 echo "</td>";
 
 echo "</tr><tr><td>";  
 $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => '5'
 );
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='survey_id' value='$row->survey_id'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />";
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " 5";
 $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => ' 4'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo " 4 ";
 echo "</td></tr><tr>";
  
}
   
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>";
 
 $data=array(
  'name' => 'submit',
  'value' => 'send',
  'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
   'id' => 'survey_submit'
 );
 echo form_submit($data);
 echo "</td></tr>";
 echo form_close();
    

    echo "</table>";
    
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: No.Just nothing change. I want to use this example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html#

Comment: can u make it in fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L2v8yjsd/1/   here it works, but in my example..it des not

Comment: how can we debug that ?

Comment: How to load JQuery properly, maybe this is my mistake, here in fiddle I select it from dropqown..

Comment: You've included dataTable twice in your JSFiddle, which is working with only one such as : https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js (try using `https`)

Comment: In fiddle, it is working, but in my project - not working.

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jej28eex/) without using External Resources from dropdown. You're not showing us the code that make it fail.

Comment: My code in project is shown up, in my question. It fails. How should be these links for JQuery and Data Tables? :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the links. Please post ALL the code, there is definitely something you're not showing us. I've just copied the code to a text file, saved it as .html and dragged it to a browser window - works fine. [https://jsfiddle.net/L2v8yjsd/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/L2v8yjsd/7/)

Comment: Ok now I'll edit my question and I'll write all the code.

Comment: Instead of using echo for the <table>, try using normal html.  I wonder if it's something to do with the table not existing in the dom.

Comment: Nothing changed. Please try to save my view in a file to see if there is a mistake or it is shown Data Tables.

Comment: Saving as a file won't work because you're building the HTML dynamically, and I'm sure that this is where your problem lies. I'm not familiar with PHP so I don't know what the alternative is, but it seems like a messy way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the problem. When I use pure html, it is working. When I use "echo" it does not work! I'll try to edit my php code - to have pure html to show data tables! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code and now it shows data tables and each question from my servey is in another row, but when I click submit button, it does not submit any data. 
My code now is:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css"  />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "lengthMenu": [[1], [1]]
    } );

} );

 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<?php
$survey_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
<table  id="example" >
  <thead>
      <tr><th>Въпрос</th></tr>
    </thead>
      
    <tbody>
    <?php
echo validation_errors();

foreach ($survey as $row)
{
 
 $row->question_id=$this->uri->segment(4);
 $question_id=$this->uri->segment(4);
 ?>
 <tr>
 <?php 
 $attributes = array('id' => 'myform');
 echo form_open('index/survey_fill/' .$survey_id  , $attributes); ?>
   <td> 
 <?php echo "$row->question"; ?><br/>
 <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; ?>
     $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => '5'
 );
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='survey_id' value='$row->survey_id'>"; ?>
 <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; 
  echo form_radio($data); 
 echo " 5 ";
 $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
  'value' => ' 4'
 );
 echo form_radio($data);
 echo "4 ";
?>
 </td></tr>
  
<?php 
}
?>
   
    <tr><td>
   <?php 
?>
 <input type="submit" id="button" name = "submit" value="Submit"> 
 </td></tr>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 
 
 </tbody>
    </table>
    

 
 </body>
 </html>
```

My model is:

```html
$answers=($this->input->post('answer'));

        if (null !==($this->input->post('submit'))) {
            $date = new DateTime("now"); 

            foreach($answers as $question_id=>$answer)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata['user_id'],
                    'question_id'=>$question_id,
                    'answer'=>$answer,              
                    'created_at'=>$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
$this->db->insert('survey_answers', $data);
                
            }
              if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
            {
                 
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
```